# Mongoose search for items on array containing _id with aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

For example, i have  a document like this

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "example name" 
}, 
{
    _id: 2,
    name: "example name 2" 
},
```

I wound like to pass an array with ids, example: [1, 2], and receive back these documents selected within aggregation mongoose method

Comment: try this:
todo.items.find({_id: {$in: [ObjectId("5ea38cf58bc5e6b27d4031db"), ObjectId("5ea38d068bc5e6b27d4031dc")]}})

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i need it with aggregate()

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([{ $match: { _id: { $in: [1, 2] }}}])`